# Does Multiverse exist in MCU?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, spider-man-far-from-home

From the *Spider-Man: Far From Home trailer*, we all get to know that Mysterio is coming from another Earth and the multiverse exists.

In the movie, it was revealed that,

> Mysterio was lying, and he is from this Earth, and all the Elementals are his creations using technology.

So I was wondering, does the multiverse exist in the MCU?

Comment: It's called MCU, not MCM :-)

Comment: Too bad **Spider-Man: Into the Spider-Verse** isn't part of MCU, that would have made it clear.

Comment: Now, it is confirmed with the phase 4 movie Doctor Strange in the Multiverse of Madness: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marvel_Cinematic_Universe:_Phase_Four#Doctor_Strange_in_the_Multiverse_of_Madness_(2021)

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Yes, it exists and previous films hinted at it too. From *Doctor Strange*:

> "This universe is only one of an infinite number. Worlds without end. Some benevolent and life-giving. Others filled with malice and hunger. Dark places, where powers older than time lie... ravenous... and waiting. Who are you in this vast multiverse, Mr. Strange?" -  Ancient One

Also from the word of god:

> Asked whether the ending of Spider-Man: Far From Home means that fans will never see a multiverse in the MCU, Feige told Fandango: "No, it just means [Mysterio] was full of shit.
>
> "I mean, in Doctor Strange, we hear the Ancient One talk about the multiverse, so we've already established it as a thing." - [digitalspy](https://www.digitalspy.com/movies/a28322154/marvel-boss-kevin-feige-multiverse-mcu/)

If you want to know all the mention and occurrences of multiverse then the [MCU Wiki](https://marvelcinematicuniverse.fandom.com/wiki/Multiverse) lists them well.

Comment: The other thing that might add to this are the events of Endgame and both Ant-Man movies.

Comment: @DariM added wiki link with all mentions.

Comment: Isn't DariM referring to more than that?  I have not seen Endgame but isn't most that movie's plot driven by the need to resolve the problem without doing anything that would cause additional timelines to split from the one they are on?  Isn't there even a main character who dies in the main timeline and is replaced by one from a different timeline?

Comment: @krb yeah but I think one example and a official interview was better then each example

Comment: Is Agents of S.H.E.I.L.D. MCU? I know it's intersected with it on occasion at least. They just pretty much confirmed the multiverse in the current AoS season...

Comment: @T.J.Crowder yes it's canon

Comment: @AnkitSharma - Thanks. Yeah, I know it's canon, but I wasn't sure *which* canon, since Marvel likes its multiverses. Or at least they do here in Earth-616. ;-)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder that's something that confused me from Spider-Man: Far From Home; Marvel previously metioned that the MCU was Earth-199999, while Mysterio mentioned that that Earth was 616, which is Marvel Comics' main universe.

Comment: @JoshPart note again the quote in the answer, "[Mysterio] was full of shit." MCU is still Earth-199999.

Comment: Really wish The Ancient One hadn't used the term "multiverse" - that is not what she was describing. She was describing the various dimensions, which all would exist within Earth-199999, like the Dark Dimension.

Comment: @krb The reason for that plot-point is fairly simple: The absence of the Infinity Stones is bad for the Universe, and causes a split.  So, not sending them back would mean saving 1 universe, but at the cost of dooming 4 universes instead (No-Space-verse, No-Time-or-Mind-verse, No-Soul-or-Power-verse and No-Reality-verse).  Being heroes, they're not going to pick the "murder 4 people to unsnap 0.5 people" option.

Comment: @AllisonC I know he was lying; it just caught my attention that he specificaly mentioned Earth-616; it made me wonder if it was just an easter egg or if it actualy meant something.

Comment: @JoshPart It caught my attention, too, and immediately struck me as wrong, so I figured it was an Easter Egg. He could have picked literally any number, so I can't see any other reason to use 616

Comment: @AllisonC I think it was an easter egg for comic fans, who would know definitively that Mysterio is lying. Granted, we already knew from the comics what kind of person he was, but this was further confirmation that _nothing_ he said could be trusted.

Answer (score 5):

Something of a meta-answer - the MCU is designated as Earth-199999 by Marvel. There haven't been any on-screen visits to comic universes or on-page visits to the movie universe, but apparently the Young Avengers visited off-screen ([See the 'notes' section here](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Young_Avengers_Vol_2_8)) at one point.

This doesn't absolutely prove the existence of the multiverse in the MCU, but does strongly imply it.